# Могу ли я использовать сообщение об ошибке для классификации ошибки?

Tags: python

Я пишу обёртку над несколькими архивами наподобие `Patool`. Я хочу оповестить пользователя, если архив (какой бы он не был) требует пароль для распаковки, а также если пароль не верен. Для этого я использую пользовательские типы исключений

```
class WrongPasswordError(ValueError):
    ''' Raised when the password for unpacking the archive is incorrect. '''

class PasswordRequiredError(ValueError):
    ''' Raised when a password is required to unpack an archive, but it is not specified.  '''
```

Таким образом, когда я пытаюсь распаковать Rar архив, я использую следующий перехват исключений:

```
def extract_file(self, file_path, output_path, password=None):
        try:
            if password is not None:
                self.archive_obj.extract(file_path, path=output_path, pwd=password)
            else:
                self.archive_obj.extract(file_path, path=output_path)
            return True
        except rarfile.PasswordRequired as e:
            raise PasswordRequiredError(str(e))
        except rarfile.RarWrongPassword as e:
            raise WrongPasswordError(str(e))
```

Это удобно, ведь библиотека `rarfile` предоставляет исключения для обоих таких случаев.
Но я не могу использовать тот же подход для Zip архива, ведь для обоих случаев он возвращает лишь `RuntimeError`, которые отличаются между собой лишь сообщением.

```
# фрагмент кода Zipfile:
...
if h != check_byte:
    raise RuntimeError("Bad password for file %r" % zipinfo.orig_filename)
...


# другой фрагмент кода
...
if not pwd:
    raise RuntimeError("File %r is encrypted, password "
                       "required for extraction" % name)
...
```

Мне приходится перехватывать это исключение и исследовать его сообщение об ошибке, чтобы разделить эти два исключения и отличить их от любых других исключений следующим образом:

```
def extract_file(self, file_path, output_path, password=None):
        try:
            if password is not None:
                self.archive_obj.extract(file_path, path=output_path, pwd=password)
            else:
                self.archive_obj.extract(file_path, path=output_path)
        except RuntimeError as e:
            stringed = str(e)
            if 'password required for extraction' in stringed:
                raise PasswordRequiredError(stringed)
            elif 'Bad password' in stringed:
                raise WrongPasswordError(stringed)
            else:
                raise
```

Я полагаю, что это может вызвать проблемы с производительностью, зависит от реализации библиотеки, которая может измениться и вообще выглядит весьма непитонично и ненадёжно. `Python` предписывает вызывать преимущественно встроенные исключения вместо пользовательских и `zipfile` успешно следует этой концепции.

---

Есть ли более чистый и питонический способ решить проблему с разделением исключений?

Comment: Если сам модуль zipfile бросает такие исключения - то видимо текст проверять. Если вы не собираетесь пароли брутфорсить, то проблем с производительностью не должно быть :) Если собираетесь - то разве что переписать код библиотеки, либо найти другую реализацию такой библиотеки.

Comment: Ну а куда деваться. Всё-таки кастомные исключения удобнее обрабатывать. Да, это жёсткая привязка к конкретной реализации, но других вариантов тут нет.

Comment: @insolor понял, спасибо. Тогда оставлю так пока.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Можно просто проверить наличие флага encrypted в соответствующем объекте ZipInfo, исключения для этого не нужны вообще

Comment: `MASK_ENCRYPTED = 1 << 0; is_encrypted = zi.flag_bits & MASK_ENCRYPTED` (где `zi` это объект ZipInfo) ([источник](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.6/Lib/zipfile.py#L1594))

Comment: (правда, для проверки на неправильность пароля, похоже, придётся всё-таки читать текст исключения)